# My login code allows users with different username but same password access

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

Im having a problem with my login code.
for example 
user 1 account details:
email: hello
password: hello2
user 2 account details:
email: hi
password: hi2

my problem is when user 1  uses hello as user name and hi2 as password, he gets access same with user 2 when he uses hi as user name and hello2 as password he gets access too. Also even though the wrong password is input but correct email it still gives access 

here is my code

```
public function does_user_exist($email,$hashed)
    {



        $query = "Select * from users where email='$email' and password = '$hashed'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $json['success'] = ' Welcome '.$email;
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this -> connection);
        }
```

I think the if statement is the problem but i really have no idea how to solve it. Please help me thanks!

Comment: update: also even though when the password is wrong but username is correct it also allows access.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that the `email` is used as the `username.` Also, if the email addresses are unique, then the issue has to be with the `hashed` password portion.

Comment: my email database field is unique and i think my hashed password is fine. my problem is if atleast 1 field is in the database it gives access....

Comment: Can I see the code where you're hashing the password and posting it to the `does_user_exist` method?

Comment: ' $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
                $salt = 'aBc_2g_@_CaMeElToEz';
                $hashed = hash('sha256',password1 . $salt);
  
  if(!empty($email) && !empty($password1)){
   
   $user-> does_user_exist($email,$hashed);'

Comment: It's like i got my own email then i use your password not mine but that password is in the database, it gives me access...

Comment: Shouldnt `password1` be a variable  - `$hashed = hash('sha256', password1 . $salt); `

Comment: is it ok to set the password field UNIQUE in registration? do you think it's a good solution?

Comment: You can, but I don't believe thats the issue, as long as the `email` is unique then you should be fine. Try removing the hash code entirely (Registration & Login), insert the raw password in the table and try to login again.

Comment: I think you are correct. but why does it accept any password even not listed in the database?  Is my query above correct? The result should be 0 if the query failed but im still wondering why it accepts any passwords.

Comment: I will code something and post it as an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I took some time and wrote some code + tested it out thoroughly.I would advise you to copy and paste my examples in your pages respectively. Also, you will noticed that I passed `$mysqli` to the method, if you passed your connection globally, you can remove `$mysqli` from my examples method.

- Point One

  Please verify that the password that's being sent to the DB on the `registration` page is hashed properly, code below:

  ```
   $email = $_POST['email']; 
   $password1 = $_POST['password'];

   $salt = 'aBc_2g_@_CaMeElToEz'; 
   $hashed = hash('sha256', $password1 . $salt);
  ```
- Point Two

  Do the same thing as in `Point One` for your login page.
- Final Point

  ```
    public function does_user_exist($email, $hashed, $mysqli){

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users where email ='$email'   
    and password = '$hashed'");
   return $result->num_rows;

  }

  if(does_user_exist($email,$hashed, $mysqli) == 1){
      echo 'Welcome to the dashboard';
    }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the effort..This seems to be the solution.